# Not Able to Access size or element of Nested list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nested-lists

I'm getting error while accessing the size or element of inner list in Java.

[This is the Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMzH8.png)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
    List<Integer> list4 = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);

    list.add(list2);
    list.add(list3);
    list.add(list4);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i).get(j)+ " ");
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your Imports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: It's better to copy your stacktrace to your question, instead of attaching it as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of the list `q` is missing the information of what kind of objects it contains.

```
List<List<Integer>> q = new ArrayList<>();
```

Without this information, the only thing the compiler can know is that it contains objects of some kind, so `q.get()` must have type `Object`. But there are no `get()` nor `size()` methods in `Object` class, and that's the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `List<List<Integer>> q = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `List q = new ArrayList();` since you are inserting a group of lists in `q`.

Answer (score 0):

Update you loop code with following, basically you need to cast the q.get(i) into List.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ((List) q.get(i)).size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(((List) q.get(i)).get(j)+ " ");
          }
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps.